# Android Fragment backstack and Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments - a , b and c. 
Fragment a shows some items, fragment b same as fragment a , fragment c contains 3 tabs. As I open fragment A --> b --> c and go back to fragment b and again open fragment c, then onCreateView for each tab, not getting called and all tabs are blank. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You said you are showing not creating so check onResume() and onPause()

Comment: where fragment c has tabs

Comment: tab like a ViewPager or TabHost?

Comment: can I see some code

Comment: yes tabs like ViewPager

Comment: try this: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount());

Comment: The problem when back from fragment c to b and go to c again not in tabs  fragments

Comment: the answer is  using  chidFragmentManager instead of using   fragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

There is something you dont do in the onResume of fragment c which is necessary for contents of the tabs. So as a matter of facts nothing is done in that situation because c was paused only! So my advice do this:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //Paste the same code you have and used in onCreateView() and run again.
    //If nothing happens override onStart and do the same thing!
    //else post some codes so that we can easily figure where the problem is..
    }
```